# php apache ddos attack protect, create a custom blacklist

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, ddos

I have a wordpress site. recently under a serious ddos attack in `wp-login.php`. I have renamed `wp-login.php` to a new `mysitename-login.php`. and creat a new empty file with name `wp-login.php`. I have joined cloudflare, still received attack log in `access_log`. I have tried `mod_evasive`, but it will kill `googlebot`

Now I am manully add them into my `.htaccess` like

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order allow,deny
 deny from 108.162.253.180
 deny from 173.245.48.134
 deny from 173.245.49.187
 deny from 173.245.51.180     
 deny from 173.245.54.66
 deny from 108.162.219.
 deny from 109.239.235.
 allow from all
</Limit>
```

And I have an idea to create the `.htaccess` dynamic.

in current `wp-login.php`

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// INSERT INTO ip_table (ip) values ($ip);
// ip is unique index
$html='<Limit GET POST>/n/r'
$html.=//select * from ip_table   loop all
$html.='allow from all/n/r</Limit>';
$html.=<<<TXT
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
TXT;
file_put_content($html,'/var/www/html/.htaccess');
```

But I am afraid, if there have some problem during the file_put_content, the `.htaccess` is broken, my site will be broken too...

Any better way, to create a blacklist by using the robot access `wp_login.php` and no risk to be broken site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Blacklist, why not make a Whitelist? This wouldn't work if you allow all users to login to Wordpress, for example if you're using a membership plugin, but if only you and a few select Admins login, then just get everyone's IP address and add those to your .htaccess file like this:

```
## Prevent anyone not on my ip whitelist from accessing wp admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/wp-admin|/wp-login.php).*$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=222.222.222.222
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=333.333.333.333
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the real visitor in my page still could login and register, I just rename the login `wp-login.php` to  `mysitename-login.php` in all of my page, the login link point to `mysitename-login.php`, so if you are a human, click by mouse, you can find my real login page, else if you are a bot, just scan and attack `wp-login.php` sorry, I tried to fish you into my blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

What about using mod_evasive for Apache? This way you can easily block all IPs that try to connect to the certain URL very often in a short period of time.

You could block all IPs that will try to connect to your fake login page as well.